# Scanner throws NoSuchElementException on nextInt

Tags: java

The logic is working fine, however when the while loop reaches its end and start over, when it come to read again my next option from the keyboard using this line -> option = kb.nextInt(); . it gives me an Exception, more precisely this one below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at view.ClientFacade.main(ClientFacade.java:18)
```

Down below there is my code, why the hell this Scanner is generating this error? Is there other ways to read from the keyboard?

```
public class ClientFacade {
    public static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean exit = false;
        int option = 0;
        RegistrationController rc = new RegistrationController();

        while(exit == false){
            System.out.println("Menu:");
            System.out.println("1 - Sign up on service.");

            option = kb.nextInt(); //ERROR ON THIS LINE WHEN IT EXECUTES ON THE SECOND LOOP

            switch(option){

            case 0:{
                exit = true;
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                rc.userSignUp();
                break;
            }
            default:{
                System.out.println("Invalid option.");
                break;
            }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method below is on another class file RegistrationController.java, so it is instantiated by the rc viariable above.

```
public void userSignUp(){
        User usr = new User();
        RegistrationController rc = new RegistrationController();
        String regex = "$(\\w)+(\\,)(\\w)+(\\,)(\\d){2,3}(\\,)[F,M](\\,)(\\w)+(@)(\\w)+(.)(\\w)+((.)(\\w)+)(,)(\\w)+^";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input a single line separated by COMMA,"
                + " the software will validade your entry.\n"
                + "1 - Your First Name, 2 - Your Second Name,"
                + " 3 - Your Age, 4 - Your Gender \n(F or M in UPPER CASE)"
                + " 5 - Your Email, 6 - Your Password:\n");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        s = s.trim();
        System.out.println("trimmed"); //DEBUG
        String [] k = s.split(",");
        char[] c = k[3].toCharArray();

        if (Pattern.matches(regex, s)){
            usr.setAdmLevel(0);
            usr.setName(k[0]+" "+k[1]);
            usr.setAge(Integer.parseInt(k[2]));
            usr.setGender(c[0]);
            usr.setEmail(k[4]);
            usr.setPassword(k[5]);
            if (rc.registerUser(usr) != 0){
                System.out.println("Your are signed up! Your ID: "+usr.getId());
            }else {
                System.out.println("A problem ocurred, not registered.");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Wrong input pattern, try again.");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
```

Comment: You've run to the end of the `Stream` but there are no more matching tokens...try adding `kb.nextLine();` after `option = kb.nextInt();`

Comment: thank you very much! it just worked, yes, as you said I was closing the sc inside the method, I tought id would close the system.in just inside it, but it closes all the program input stream, got it! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `sc.close()` it closes your underlying stream, which is `System.in`; once you close `System.in` the only way to get it back is to restart your program.

Per the [`close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29) Javadoc,

> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked

Comment: thank you very much! it just worked, yes, as you said I was closing the sc inside the method, I tought id would close the system.in just inside it, but it closes all the program input stream, got it! :)

Answer (score 7):

You closed the `Scanner` which closed the underlying stream. Don't do that with your standard ins and outs.

Comment: thank you very much! it just worked, yes, as you said I was closing the sc inside the method, I tought id would close the system.in just inside it, but it closes all the program input stream, got it! :)