# Scanner throwing NoSuchElementException on the second time of .nextInt();

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The first time menu() is displayed, I'm able to enter input and runGame() works. The second time the menu is displayed, the program is crashing on the line int answer = scanner.nextInt() with a java.util.NoSuchElementException. It seems that there isn't a 'nextInt' to read in, but I don't ever have the chance to enter it the second time.

```
public void runGame(){
    int userPick = 0;
    userPick = menu();
    while (userPick != 10){  //user exists with a choice of 10
        switch (userPick){
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("User picked 1");
                break; 
            case 2:
                ...
            default:
               ...
        }
       userPick = menu();
}

public int menu(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please choose an integer from 0 - 10(quit)");
    int answer = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();
    return answer; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you opening and closing a `Scanner` inside a loop? Doesn't that seem redundant?

Comment: This is how we learned to use Scanners @DebosmitRay. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per, [Scanner throws NoSuchElementException on nextInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175249/scanner-throws-nosuchelementexception-on-nextint?rq=1)

When you call scanner.close() it closes your underlying stream, which is System.in; once you close System.in the only way to get it back is to restart your program.

Removing the close took care of the issue.